# How work mocking of a Mapper inside a tested method with Spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, spring-test

I need to test this method :

```
    @PostMapping(path = { API.PATH.SEND, API.PATH.PUBLIC_SEND })
public ResponseEntity<MessageDto> send(@RequestBody MessageDto messageDto) {

    log.info("Sending message {}", messageDto.getMessage());

    final var sendedMessageId = this.envoyerMessage.execute(
            WebMessageMapper.INSTANCE.messageDtoToMessage(messageDto)
    );

    messageDto.setId(sendedMessageId.getValue());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(messageDto);
}
```

So I created this test class :

```
@Tag("unitTest")
@WebMvcTest(MessageControllerV1.class)
public class MessageControllerV1Test {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private EnvoyerMessage envoyerMessage;

    @MockBean
    private LireMessage lireMessage;

    private WebMessageMapper webMessageMapper;

    @Test
    public void send() throws Exception {
        String content = "{ \"id\":1\"\", \"message\": \"Test variable\" }";
        this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/api/message/add")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(content)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().is(200));
    }
}
```

But I get NullPointerException on sendedMessageId.
How does it work to integrate Mapper mock in this test ?

Comment: Where do you actually _mock_ `envoyerMessage.execute`? You've injected a mock, which returns `null` unless you tell it to return something else.

Comment: @RobSpoor I've injected EnvoyerMessage with MockBean so I thought execute() can be executed without something else. So I need to simulate both execute() and the mapper ?

Comment: You need to use calls like `Mockito.when`, `Mockito.doReturn`, etc. For instance: `when(envoyerMessage.execute(any())).thenReturn(sendedMessageId)`, where `sendedMessageId` is the value to return.